# Adding background image with 'ng-style' in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I seem unable to use a controller to set the CSS background property of a div. Here is my code so far, as per the documentation:

HTML:

```
<div class="hero" ng-controller="HeroCtrl" ng-style="heroImage"></div>
```

JS:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('AppliedSiteApp').controller('HeroCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.heroImage = {
        background: 'images/brick.jpg'
    };

    console.log($scope.heroImage);

});
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I have also tried to replicate this setup in a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/hzxNa/1/). Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$scope.heroImage = {
    background: 'url(images/brick.jpg)'
};
```

`background-image` requires `url()` to work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use css' `url()` function for background images , like this:

```
'background-image': 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvI9.jpg)'
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PFUY0w?p=preview

Comment: To use with a dynamic data you should do ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + data.url + ')' }">

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS now suppoorts [`ng-style`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle).

So now you can use `ng-style="{ backgroundImage: variableInScope + '/some/string' }"`